# Unable connect to MongoDB listening on localhost (on host) from within a docker container

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, tornado-motor

On Linux Ubuntu 22.04 I have created a docker container with a simple python script that has to connect to a MongoDB instance working on the host and listening on localhost.
To have a reproducible example consider what follows.
The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl pip micro netcat -y
COPY requirements.txt app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

The requirements file contains:

```
fastapi==0.85.1
uvicorn==0.19.0
motor==3.1.0dev
black==22.10.0
python-dotenv==0.21.0 
orjson==3.8.0
requests==2.28.1
```

While the python script (inside app/db directory) is mongodb.py and contains:

```
import asyncio
import requests
from motor.motor_asyncio import (
    AsyncIOMotorClient,
    AsyncIOMotorCollection,
)

 
from bson.codec_options import DEFAULT_CODEC_OPTIONS

def get_collection(
     
) -> AsyncIOMotorCollection:
    # SET OPTION TO RETURN DATES AS TIMEZONE AWARE
    options = DEFAULT_CODEC_OPTIONS.with_options(tz_aware=True)


    motor_client = AsyncIOMotorClient(
        "mongodb://usr:pwd@host.docker.internal:27020/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=Replica1"
    )
    database = motor_client["DBNAME"]
    # APPLY OPTIONS TO RETURN DATETIMES AS TIMEZONE AWARE
    return database.get_collection(collName, codec_options=options)


async def main():
    # client = ClientMotor().client
    coll = get_collection()
    response=requests.get('http://host.docker.internal')
    print(response.text)
    async for doc in coll.find({}).limit(10):
        print(doc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(
            main()
        )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

On host, I have installed and started NGINX that forwards stream to MongoDB from PORT 27020 to default port 27017 (always localhost).
The previous code works fine if not within a docker container (specifying localhost instead of the host.docker.internal) and I can connect to MongoDB from Compose by specifying PORT 27020 in the connection string.
If I build the container with

```
docker build -t test_motor .
```

and thereafter run it with

```
docker run -it --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway test_motor  bash
```

Running

```
python3 mongodb.py.
```

From within /app/db, I correctly get a response from NGINX but I'm not able to connect to MongoDB.
If I execute from within the docker container

```
nc -zvw10 host.docker.internal 27020
```

the host/port is reachable.
What's the problem? I don't want to run the container with host=net, the only working solution so far!

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved as following.
I had to add **directConnection=True** in the connection string to MongoDB and I had to set **bindIp: 0.0.0.0 in MongoDB configuration file** (in /etc/mongod.conf).
To be clearer I changed motor_client as follows:

```
motor_client = AsyncIOMotorClient(
 username="user",
 password="secret",
 connectTimeoutMS=5000,
 socketTimeoutMS=5000,
 authSource="admin",
 host="host.docker.internal",
 port=27017,
 directConnection=True
)
```

Actually I don't know why I had to set **directConnection=True** but this, in my configuration, solved the problem.